# Looking for PHP script/engine for photographic community. Preferably freeware

Tags: php, gallery, photo

I'm looking for PHP script/engine for photographic community. Want to create local photographers community where people can discuss various photographic topics and share their pictures, I see it more like forum/blog type, when user can attach pictures from other galleries and create own local gallery as well.
Preferably freeware.

Comment: phpBB with some plug-ins for images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few that might do what you want - I've not delved too deeply into any of them.

[Pixelpost](http://www.pixelpost.org/)

[Gallery](http://gallery.menalto.com/features)

[Coppermine](http://coppermine-gallery.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Go with [Gallery](http://gallery.menalto.com/features) It has the most features, amazing permissions abilities, and customizable! You can even integrate it into most content management Systems out there!